# GHC cannot find libraries on fresh install of Haskell-Platform

Tags: haskell, cabal, parsec, haskell-platform

I'm trying to learn how to use Haskell, but I've run into a little roadblock. I'm using MacOSX 10.12.6 and installed Haskell Platform using:

```
$ brew cask install haskell-platform
```

with no modifications. When I try to compile a program with `parsec` imported, Haskell-Platform can't find it:

```
$ ghc -v test.hs 
...
package parsec-3.1.11-DPgnR92AWEaFOaixmwipet is unusable due to shadowed dependencies:
mtl-2.2.1-19EL8AGBsN3DnnOhrC9xY3 text-1.2.2.2-EGUst8sqNAZCw1xLPcmcMH
...
test.hs:2:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Parsec’
    Locations searched:
    Text/Parsec.hs
    Text/Parsec.lhs
    Text/Parsec.hsig
    Text/Parsec.lhsig
|
2 | import Text.Parsec
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

parsec is installed:

```
$ ghc-pkg list | grep -e 'parsec'
attoparsec-0.13.2.0
parsec-3.1.11
```

So I have a few questions:

- What does it mean by shadowed dependencies?
- Where does GHC look for libraries?
- Where does GHC look for user libraries vs system wide libraries?
- Can this path be modified?

Comment: Could you try to make a cabal package (`cabal init`) and build it with cabal or stack (you'll neet to `stack init` as well then)

Comment: I would suggest you to get started with stack: https://haskell-lang.org/get-started

Comment: @Sibi Stack works great, and has good documentation for these sorts of issues. I can use `stack install parsec` to dick around, or for projects, I can add dependencies to the `projectName.cabal` file.

Comment: This was likely an issue with the binary platform builds that's just been resolved. c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508231/issue-installing-snap-on-macos-sierra/46599487#46599487

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug with 8.2.1 binary platform builds, and a new release was cut to fix the issue you encountered.

Details on the bug, and the new release are provided at https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2017-October/127979.html